# How to draw graphs with arrows, points, and curly brackets

Tags: arrows, graphs, brackets, points

I am trying to learn how to use tikz package to draw these two graphs, but I don't know how to start. Could anyone help show how to this kind of graphs? Thanks.[image]

Comment: Have you looked at the minimal introduction to TikZ? See this https://cremeronline.com/LaTeX/minimaltikz.pdf and a lot of your questions will be answered.

Comment: Thank you so much, that actually helps a lot!